# How to use a variable as array index in Jekyll include

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a data file containing objects that I want to use specified indexes in a Jekyll include.

My page is calling the include like so:

```
{% include components/header-filter.html items="0" %}
```

Where `0` is the index I want to use in this case.

My include is:

```
{% assign filterID = include.items %}
{% capture id %}{{ filterID }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign filter = site.data.filters[id] %}
```

This works until it gets to the 3rd line, at which point it outputs nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the following changes:

1. Call the include with `items` as a integer not a string:

   ```
   {% include components/header-filter.html items=0 %}
   ```

   (note that this assumes you have no path issues with the location of the include. Running jekyll locally it insisted I put that in `/_inlcudes`)
2. Remove the `capture` line and just pass `filterID` to the next line - it isn't needed and was possibly causing an issue:

   ```
   {% assign filterID = include.items %}
   {% assign filter = site.data.filters[filterID] %}
   ```
3. And then to your comment "it outputs nothing", you'll need to output something (might have just been omitted from your example, but for completeness, let's assume `filters` has a filed called `name`):

   ```
   {{ filter.name }}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was #1 that was the issue, it was treating the 0 as a string when I wanted just the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this by 'cutting out the middle man'
    {% include components/header-filter.html items=0 %}

```
{% assign filter = site.data.filters[include.items] %}
```

The reason yours wasn't working is because the capture was converting it into a string. You can convert a string to a integer with a maths filter. For example:
`{% assign id = id | plus: 0 %}` the value of it wont change but liquid will now treat it as an integer.

Alternatively you can just call it as an integer by omitting the quote marks. `{% include components/header-filter.html items=0 %}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `forloop` helper

- forloop.length -- length of the entire for loop
- forloop.index -- index of the current iteration
- forloop.index0 -- index of the current iteration (zero based)
- forloop.rindex -- how many items are still left?
- forloop.rindex0 -- how many items are still left? (zero based)
- forloop.first -- is this the first iteration?
- forloop.last -- is this the last iteration?

```
{% for offer in site.data.companies %}
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="{{forloop.index0}}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This will give

```
<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0"></li>

<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>

<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>

...
```